# Found viruses on my machine by clamTK. Need help catching hackers

Tags: security

I ran clamTK on my 14.04 laptop and found 3 PUA's including one for phishing. I found them in

```
/home/Draeko/.cache/mozilla/firefox/jsobiwpi.default/Cache/9/08/64101d01 
.../Cache/4/2C/BS149d01
.../Cache/2/B7/122B8d01
```

The first two were PUA.Script.Packed-1 and  the third one was the PUA.Phishing.Bank . I keep everything high security on my distro so these were the result of hackers. I have a gmail account that I can't access which also was hacked (I was being subscribed to newsletters and then when I contacted the companies they said I must've been hacked) and the only IP that showed up was my own in the account history section. Can someone please help me catch these hackers? I've been dealing with it for too long.

Comment: You may want to upload your suspected files to some online antivirus services to verify that it is a real virus or malware, not false positives

Comment: The false positive PUA.Script.Packed-2 is flooding logs daily, even though `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` already has by default `DetectPUA false`  Any idea how to disable scanning PUA in clamtk-scan/freshclam/clamav?

Answer (score 1):

Clam is known for producing false positives in the firefox cache directory. It's almost definitely not a virus or any sort of hack.

Consider reading this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) and inform yourself "myth-free" about linux security.

Also afaik, there are no known linux viruses, that could affect your desktop, so clam is going to scan your system only for windows-viruses.